# Jquery object function waits for all the statement to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I am learning a jquery and new to it I created a jquery object like

$(function () {a();b();c()})

As I have 3 method call under the Jquery object function and the Jquery function waits for end of every method call after that only displays the result . So I wanted to know is there a way that we can show work information of those methods which has completed the work , like if a() has been called and work is done it should display the result and should not wait for other methods to to be called and processed .

Comment: I think you should see async functions documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Please show us more code. How you are showing results. There is a lot of ways to do that, but it is imposible to figure it out w/o more details. @MiqayelSrapionyan I do not think async has something to show results. Author wants to see results during processing, so he need to implement it in function logic.

Comment: As author says > like if a() has been called and work is done it should display the result and should not wait for other methods.
So i understand it as async. Thanks for your comment. @DanielHornik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle async functions in JavaScript. The easiest way is using callbacks if you are new to this language.

```js
function a(callbackA) {
   // do something...
   console.log('A')
   callbackA();
}

function b(callbackB) {
   // do something...
   console.log('B')
   callbackB();
}

function c() {
   // do something...
   console.log('C')
}

// usage:
a(function() {
    b(function() {
        c();
    });
});
```